# Iframe that works on PC and IOS

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to iframe a google-site to an outside url, but the problem seems to be that I either have two scroll-bars in when viewed in chrome, or can't scroll when viewed in IOS if I use a full-screen iframe. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">    
<iframe src="https://sites.google.com/site/tobiaskonitzer/" 
style="overflow:scroll; position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px;     
right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0;    
overflow:auto; z-index:999999;"> Your browser doesn't support IFrames >< </iframe>
```

Many thanks,
Tobi

Answer (score 0):

If you use the code below it makes the iframe 100%, meaning that there is no scroll bar, no white space, it is exactly the same size as the the browser, it uses simple HTML coding:

```
<iframe src="mypage.html" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
```

Also use the body 0% margin:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, but it still does not allow scrolling on any IOS device. This seems to be tough to figure out!

Comment: Try searching on w3schools.com

Comment: I don't think you can scroll on IOS.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I am asking whether there is a way to "allow" for scrolling on IOS devices. Thanks,

Comment: Sorry i couldnt help, I didn't really understand.